# 'X' Pattern in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to generate a X pattern in SQL like below:

```
100001
010010
001100
010010
100001
```

It's a Grid Structure of 5x6 : 5 records with a value of 6 digits.

It may have dynamic grid of a given even number like 4, 8.
Any ideas will be really helpful.

I was trying something like below, Pattern:

```
select rpad('1',level, '1') from dual connect by level <= 5
```

But this would only form a right angle triangle

```
1 
11 
111 
1111 
11111
```

Comment: How do you make any patterns using SQL?

Comment: Do you want to create a the patter as a set of results or one result with a multi line text?

Comment: Only a 6x6? Or is the size of the grid variable?

Comment: @Filburt. I am trying to generate set of results

Comment: @LukStorms Dynamic Size but always in even format.. Like 4x4, 6x6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the recursiveness of a connect is a nice method.

The query below will generate an X in grid.
With a size you can choose by changing the number in the inner query.

```
select lpad('1',y,'0')||rpad('0',n-y*2,'0')||rpad('1',y,'0') as X
from (
   select level as lvl, n, case when level<n/2 then level else n-level end as y
   from (select 6 as n from dual) 
   connect by level < n
)
order by lvl
```

The subquery will generate numbers based on n.

For example, if n = 6 then the subquery will generate:

```
lvl n  y
--- -- -- 
1   6  1
1   6  2
3   6  3
4   6  2
5   6  1
```

Then in the outer query those n and y numbers are used to calculate the amount of 0 to pad to the left, the middle and the right side.

When using 8 for n it generates the following grid:

```
10000001
01000010
00100100
00011000
00100100
01000010
10000001
```

To make it work also for the uneven numbers a few (mod)ifications are needed.

```
select lpad('1',y,'0')||rpad('0',n-y*2,'0')||case when mod(n,2) = 1 and lvl = trunc(n/2)+1 then rpad('0',y-1,'0') else rpad('1',y,'0') end as X
from (
   select level as lvl, n, case when level<trunc(n/2)+mod(n,2) then level else n+mod(n,2)-level end as y
   from (select 5 as n from dual) 
   connect by level < (case when mod(n,2) = 1 then n+1 else n end)
) q
order by lvl
```

For n = 5 that would generate:

```
10001
01010
00100
01010
10001
```